# Cookies Work On Localhost But Not Web Host

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I've actually spent a few hours looking this up but so far haven't found anything that worked in my case (as I had already cleared the bases, at least as far as I could tell). Here's the situation:

I've written up a script that writes a cookie to the system. After fiddling with it and learning how it all works, I got it to work flawlessly... for Localhost. I finished up the rest of the site and was happy that everything works great! But then I moved the site to a web host. The site is still great, except for one large problem: cookies are never written. I can not figure out why, and have even 777'd the files (they are still on a "private address" for now) and they still won't write the cookies. So here's some pseudocode for you. Hopefully someone can figure out where I'm going wrong, or what I need to be checking out.

```
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{ 
$_COOKIE["name"] = $_GET['name'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$cexp = time()+60*60*24*3650;
setcookie("name", "$name", $cexp, "/");
}
```

So one of the things people said to do is to add the URL after the path variable. I did this as well (using the format ".example.com") and that has had no impact.

What confuses me is that even now, this code works flawlessly on the local host (and I can see the cookies written to the domain "localhost") but on the hosted server I'm having no luck at all.

Any help would be much appreciated, and I'll also answer any questions to the best of my ability.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Thank you all so much for helping with this! I'm new to cookies, so this was unexplored territory. I assumed if it worked on my own server, it should work on an actual host as well. And we all know what happens when we assume...

So for anyone else with a similar problem, here would be the proper code:

```
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{ 
$name = $_GET['name'];
$cexp = time()+60*60*24*3650;
setcookie("name", "$name", $cexp, "/");
$_COOKIE["name"] = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Alternatively you could leave out the last line. I have that there as a fallback so that the data is still available without a page refresh (as it deals with information that I want to stay in a text box). Also, this stuff HAS to be at the top of the page. A big problem I had was going with a three-part site: Header, Main and Footer php files, each in their own div. Cookies have to be dealt with prior to even starting the div's, so I need to reorganize my code now.

Thanks again all!

Comment: Did you read on PHP.net? "...setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and <head> tags as well as any whitespace.

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays....."

Comment: You try to access $_COOKIE, before setcookie

Comment: @bksi Thanks for the comment. I actually did the writing to the cookie so that later on (I have calls for the cookie's information) it can be read in without page reloads. BIT CHEETAH had the same idea as you, I think (based on his code) but that didn't go anywhere either, sadly. If the issue was the order in which things were being called, wouldn't there be problems with running it on localhost too though?

Comment: you cannot *CREATE* cookies by setting $_COOKIE. You *HAVE* to use setcookie() only.

Comment: @bksi - it appears through some more fiddling with the order of things, you were right; all of the issues were due to the order (I was pulling this information from the header, which was pulled through a header div). I still don't get why this worked fine on localhost though...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment as well! I wasn't trying to create the cookie that way. It was a fallback because the input information goes in a text box (so essentially if the cookie was there, it would put the cookie's information in the box). Since the cookie can not be read without a refresh, manually setting the cookie variable is what I read was the best option for still having the information available (which would be replaced on page refresh since the actual cookie would exist)

Comment: Edited my original post with fix and other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

→ **Try this:**

```
session_start();

$test = "cheese";
$cexp = time() + (60*60*24*3650);

setcookie("test", $test, $cexp, "yourdomain.extension");

if(isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
    echo $_COOKIE["test"];
}
else {
    echo "Refresh Page!";
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work either. For some reason it's still ignoring the cookie posting. What loses me beyond that is that everything is flawless server side (with my original code I can wipe all cookies from my browsers, load the site and it will write and read the cookies fine). It's just that the web host isn't allowing it (although I do have other sites with them that use cookies and have no issues).

Comment: @Bryan Try my updated answer just to see if it will set such a cookie

Comment: Isn't session for `$_SESSION`? Anyways if you're using the default session settings it will create a cookie in the same manner as the `$_COOKIE` so I don't believe this will work.

Comment: @DaveChen The session_start() isn't necessary but I have seen stranger things happen. Nevertheless, this code attempts to set the cookie regardless without a codition, check for it, and outputs what happened. It will probably need to be ran and then refreshed.

Comment: @BITCHEETAH Thanks for your help! It actually ended up working when I removed everything except the code posted. I had said it was "pseudocode" in the beginning, and what I was doing was using a 3 part site (header, main, footer php files). Header was handling the name in this case, so I'd pull in <div id="header"> and then include the header.php file. Apparently the div code was messing this up. I'm still baffled as to why it worked flawlessly on my localhost though... now I need to go deal with a lot of re-planning the code to get these cookie calls/writes at the top, :(

Comment: Edited my original post with the fix and other info.